# .Private is 14x time bigger than /home -> disk almost full

Tags: encryption, home-directory, disk-usage, ecryptfs

I'm having an issue with my encrypted home folder:

I enabled `/home/theUser` encryption when creating `theUser`.
I don't have a proper `/home/theUser/.Private` directory (it's a link as shown by Luís de Sousa), the whole `/home/theUser` directory is encrypted.

I now have a `df -h` resulting in:

```
Filesystem             Size    Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                   189G       0  189G   0% /dev
tmpfs                   38G    146M   38G   1% /run
/dev/sda2              6,9T    5,9T  650G  91% /
tmpfs                  189G    180K  189G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                  5,0M       0  5,0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                  189G       0  189G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sdb1              235G     60M  223G   1% /opt
cgmfs                  100K       0  100K   0% /run/cgmanager/fs
tmpfs                   38G     40K   38G   1% /run/user/112
tmpfs                   38G       0   38G   0% /run/user/1020
/home/theUser/.Private   6,9T    5,9T  650G  91% /home/theUser
tmpfs                   38G       0   38G   0% /run/user/1000
```

Also, when loggin the result of `du -h` at the root of theUser's home folder I get:

```
du -h | cat > log_du_home_theUser.txt
tail log_du_home_theUser.txt

862M    ./Téléchargements
4,0K    ./Public
473G
```

which seems to mean my total home folder reach 473G.

The OS is ubuntu server, so no Trash:

```
cd /home/theUser
ls -lah .local/share/

total 96K
drwxr-xr-x 13 theUser theUser 4,0K déc.   2 14:20 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 theUser theUser 4,0K déc.  11  2014 ..
drwx------  2 theUser theUser 4,0K déc.  11  2014 applications
-rw-rw-r--  1 theUser theUser    0 déc.  11  2014 .converted-launchers
drwx------  7 theUser theUser 4,0K déc.  11  2014 evolution
-rw-rw-r--  1 theUser theUser  956 déc.  11  2014 gsettings-data-convert
drwx------  2 theUser theUser 4,0K févr.  4  2016 gvfs-metadata
drwxrwxr-x  2 theUser theUser 4,0K déc.  11  2014 icc
drwx------  2 theUser theUser 4,0K janv. 26  2017 keyrings
drwx------  3 theUser theUser 4,0K déc.  11  2014 nautilus
-rw-------  1 theUser theUser 3,4K mars  24  2015 recently-used.xbel
-rw-rw-r--  1 theUser theUser  594 janv. 26  2017 session_migration-ubuntu
drwx------  2 theUser theUser 4,0K déc.  11  2014 sounds
drwx------  3 theUser theUser 4,0K déc.  11  2014 telepathy
drwxr-xr-x  2 theUser theUser 4,0K déc.  11  2014 unity-settings-daemon
drwx------  2 theUser theUser 4,0K sept. 18  2015 unity-webapps
drwx------  3 theUser theUser 4,0K déc.  11  2014 zeitgeist
```

Why the huge diff. between `/home/theUser` (473G) and `/home/theUser/.Private` (6,9T) ?

I cannot `backup/delete/copy` the `theUser` account because of low disk space on site and would prefer to keep encrypted home if possible, all this is getting out of hand soon.

Cheers.

Comment: What's `mount` and `df -Th` say? eCryptfs is probably  adding the "false" /home/theuser line

Comment: Don't add unrelated tags just to bump your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your df output has two nearly identical lines:

```
/dev/sda2                6,9T    5,9T  650G  91% /
/home/theUser/.Private   6,9T    5,9T  650G  91% /home/theUser
```

Check with `df -T` & `mount`, but if you're using eCryptfs on your home it shows up in `df` as using the same space as it's host filesystem, your `/` in this case, even though `/home/theUser` is using much less space.

So that 5.9T is taken up by everything in `/` , not just `/home`, so there's many more files there outside of your home.

[This explanation](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ecryptfs-utils/+bug/899604/comments/3) from [Tyler Hicks](http://ecryptfs.org/about.html) (maintainer of eCryptfs) about an invalid bug report may be helpful:

> > As Dustin mentioned, the on-disk footprint is not duplicated when using eCryptfs. The eCryptfs inode, as queried by the `du -h /home/name/9726255eec083aa56dc0449a21b3319`, is an in-memory representation of the actual on-disk inode in the lower filesystem.
> >
> > Similarly, **when df is reporting filesystem usage, the reported usage of any eCryptfs mount is simply the usage amount reported by the filesystem that eCryptfs is mounted upon.**
> >
> > While the output of those commands (and my explanation) may be confusing at first, it is the expected output when dealing with a stacked filesystem like eCryptfs.

---

I can't tell if your encrypted home is taking up "too much space" beyond it's `du` size, checking `/home/.ecryptfs` and comparing it's size to your mounted home might reveal more info.

- You could try `du -h -d1 /` to see what size the main root folders are, or `-dN` to look down N folder "depths".
- I like `baobab` / Disk Usage Analyzer as a nice graphic way to see what's taking up disk space (run with sudo/as root, otherwise there's a lot of "Permission denied" messages & missing info)

Though the tools above will probably see `/home/.ecryptfs` and `/home/theUser` as separate, thus taking up twice as much space (roughly equal space). Only files in `/home/.ecryptfs` take up disk space; the mounted `/home/theUser` is a virtual decrypted "view".

*(Also, the used size in your `df` output, for `/dev/sda`, is 5.9T. The 6.9T is it's total size. And I'm unfamiliar with `... | cat > file` the pipe to cat seems unnecessary.)*

Comment: Non-commenting ("drive-by) downvoter: A comment would have been helpful, but it's still right but with more explanation now. Feel free to switch to upvote or help with a comment why it's "wrong"